The properties of the orbit-stabilizer theorem
According to the orbit-stabilizer theorem, the number of elements in a group equals the order of the orbit of element $x$ times the order of the stabilizer of $x$. So, the number of group elements can't be a prime number, right? For example, $3$, but there should be a group with 3 elements.
Also, as shown in the table, the first row represents set $X$, and the first column represents group $G$. For element $1$, according to the orbit-stabilizer theorem, the number of group elements is $6 = 2 × 3$. However, if we remove group elements $(3, 5, 6)$, then the number of group elements should be $5$, but the order of the orbit $×$ the order of the stabilizer is $2 × 2 = 4$, which does not equal $5$. I am a beginner and don't know where I went wrong. I would really appreciate your guidance.

What's wrong with the order of the orbit or stabiliser being $1$?

And, after removing $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$, is what you're left with still a group?

Let's take this step-by-step. Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $X$ and let $x \in X$.

So, the number of group elements can't be a prime number, right?

If $G$ has order $p$ prime, then we can only decomposite this as the product of two natural numbers as $p \times 1$ or $1 \times p$. So either:

$\left|\operatorname{Stab}_G(x)\right| = p$ and $\left|\operatorname{Orb}_G(x)\right| = 1$, or
$\left|\operatorname{Stab}_G(x)\right| = 1$ and $\left|\operatorname{Orb}_G(x)\right| = p$.

Both situations can happen. Let $G = \left\{(), (12)\right\}$ act on $X = \{1,2,3\}$. If we take $x = 1$, then $\operatorname{Stab}_G(x) = \{()\}$ and $\operatorname{Orb}_G(x) = \{1,2\}$. If we take $x = 3$, then $\operatorname{Stab}_G(x) = G$ and $\operatorname{Orb}_G(x) = \{3\}$.

For example, $3$, but there should be a group with 3 elements.

For any prime $p$, there exists a group of order $p$ (which is cyclic and unique up to isomorphisms).

However, if we remove group elements (3,5,6), [...]

The orbit-stabiliser theorem says something about actions of groups on sets, not actions of arbitrary subsets of groups on sets. As mentioned by @kipf in the comments, you can't just remove a group element and assume that what is left is still a group (at least, for the original group multiplication). In fact, by Lagrange's theorem, the order of a subgroup divides the order of the parent group. Since $5$ does not divide $6$, a subset of $5$ elements cannot be a subgroup of a group with $6$ elements.
The closest thing you can get, is considering the action of a subgroup $H$ of $G$. The subgroups of $G$ are $\{()\}$, $\{(),(12)\}$ and $\{(),(356),(365)\}$. For each of these subgroups, the orbit-stabiliser theorem will still work.
